# unable to build android project in phoneGap

Tags: android, cordova

I am using Phonegap desktop App to create phonegap Apps
when i try to build my android project using node.js command prompt it gives me 
following error

```
    C:\dbApp>cordova build
Running command: C:\dbApp\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat

C:\dbApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: Failed to run "ant -version", make sure you have ant installed and added
to your PATH.
    at C:\dbApp\platforms\android\cordova\lib\check_reqs.js:43:27
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:652:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
Error: C:\dbApp\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit co
de 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\SABA-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)

C:\dbApp>
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

Hello I solved My problem .
i have to just add ANT_HOME environment variable